# ¿Cómo agregar un nuevo byte a un array de bytes previamente creado?

Tags: c#, array

Estoy trabajando con arrays de bytes muy grandes y necesito agregar al final de la secuencia un byte de control. El problema que tengo es que el array no lo creo directamente yo sino que me viene dado por una función:

```
private byte[] MStoByte(MemoryStream ms)
{
    byte[] data = ms.ToArray();
    // Agregar byte de control
    return data;
}
```

La solución que se me había ocurrido es la de crear un nuevo array con un tamaño n+1 y recorrer el array principal con un bucle, pero al tratarse de arrays de más de 50.000 elementos este proceso se alarga más de lo esperado.

¿Habría alguna forma más eficiente de realizar este procedimiento?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Acabo de encontrar la solución, sería tan sencillo como usar el método `Array.Resize` para aumentar en uno su tamaño y a continuación ya podría insertar el byte de control.

```
Array.Resize(ref data, data.lenght + 1);
```